# How to save a buffer into an S3 Bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, npm

My requirement is to save a `Buffer` of an image into an `S3` bucket. I am using [gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) node module for converting an `image` to a `buffer`. But my main issue is that I need to sent the buffer directly into the S3 bucket without saving it in any local file.

My Current Code is as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
        gm = require('gm').subClass({
            imageMagick: true
        });

gm(/*buffer value*/).resize(9000)
   .toBuffer('jpg', function (err, buffer){
        fs.writeFile(filePath, buffer, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('It\'s saved!');
     });
  });
```

My Requirement is as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
        gm = require('gm').subClass({
            imageMagick: true
        });

gm(/*buffer value*/).resize(9000)
   .toBuffer('jpg', function (err, buffer){
        //S3 Upload To be done on the buffer value
});
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I used [knox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knox) npm package which helps me place the buffer into the s3 bucket.